# How to unregister phone from firebase cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello I am developing an test app using FCM I go through docs and also search on net but unable to find the option that how can a device token can be deleted from firebase database.

I have tried Firebase.getInstanceId.deleteToken but It didn't help

Answer (score 7):

Try this one

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
```

Comment: No effect. Phone still gets the push messages.

Comment: Try with topics like register and unregister topics. Send the push notification only through topic. If you are using server to handle push notification you can use http call for setting notification ON/OFF.

Comment: I've tried a combination of deleteInstanceId and deleteToken, I still receive pushes...

Comment: one additional attempt: turning off auto init using `FirebaseMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled(false)` // default behavior of `deleteInstanceId` [recreates automatically](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#deleteInstanceId) the token!!!

Comment: This worked for me without "FirebaseMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled(false)". Firebase assigned a new FCM token after revoking the old one.

Answer (score 2):

in 2019:

```
firebaseConfig = {...}
initializedFirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
initializedFirebaseApp.getItem().deleteToken().then(() => 'your logic here')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
   /**
   * Deletes the {@link FirebaseApp} and all its data. All calls to this {@link FirebaseApp}
   * instance will throw once it has been called.
   *
   * <p>A no-op if delete was called before.
   *
   * @hide
   */
FirebaseApp.getInstance().delete()
```